# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not valid

Tags: c#, linq

here is what I have...

```
public class Clinician
{
    public Guid ClinicianId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(255), Unique(1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(255), Unique(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public partial class user_mstr
{
    public Guid ldap_guid { get; set; }

    [StringLength(18)]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(13)]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
 }
```

calling interface

```
IEnumerable<Clinician> ICliniciansRepository.GetAll(Guid? locationId)
{

    return (from um in context.user_mstr
            join pm in context.provider_mstr on um.provider_id equals pm.provider_id
            join upx in context.user_provider_xref on um.provider_id equals upx.provider_id
            join upr in context.user_provider_relationship on upx.relationship_id equals upr.relationship_id
            orderby um.first_name, um.last_name
            select new Clinician
            {   
                ClinicianId = um.ldap_guid,
                FirstName = um.first_name,
                LastName = um.last_name 
             }).ToArray();

}
```

clinician Id and um.ldap_guid are of type GUID. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How is your database table?

Comment: I'm guessing the column `ldap_guid` isn't of type `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: Are you sure the bug is on that line? Try to execute the rest of the query except the select part and check if it works.

Comment: it is failing on that return line. ldap_guid is a is varchar(50) in the sql server table.

Comment: Yes, that's your issue.  A varchar(50) is not `uniqueidentifier`.  You're mapping to the wrong type.